# Is NotLeaderForPartitionException Normal During Kafka Broker Shutdowns?

Tags: apache-kafka

When I perform a controlled shutdown of a Kafka Broker in a cluster, I see this exception in the kafka_root.logs for a short while:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotLeaderForPartitionException: This server is not the leader for that topic-partition
```

Is this expected behavior?  I thought that when Kafka brokers are shutdown cleanly, the cluster would elect another broker for each partition and inform consumers about it?  Is this not the case?

Comment: You are correct. The next metadata update out to clients will let them know about the new leaders. However, you might see this in the transient between the state change because the broker has been informed it's not the least anymore but the client is still the process of getting notified. You'll see this from consumers and other brokers making replica fetcher requests but it shouldn't last long. Just a few seconds usually.